# Javascript Loop through data, process and append results

Tags: javascript

I have some data a function and need to loop the data process the lat and lon of each data field through the function and if result is smaller or equal to 20 then append the name into a div in the body of the html file. 
This last I know how to do.

This is where I am:

The data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Paul Brooks",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52.71423653147739,
      "lon": -0.6552093528558713
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Jason Orange",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52.030778298795856,
      "lon": 0.364888567109396
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark Way",
    "location": {
      "lat": 53.41899784623413,
      "lon": -1.9138465628943413
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Ben Bon",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52.30976192959104,
      "lon": -0.4014670363034498
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Chris Col",
    "location": {
      "lat": 53.45301856182801,
      "lon": -1.8765834388107732
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Von Van",
    "location": {
      "lat": 53.82771812914788,
      "lon": -0.7563793003592991
    }
  }
]
```

I also have a function have will check the distance is the lat lon.

```
function checkDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {

    //do the stuff

    return result

}
```

What I need to do is I need a loop that will read each lat and lon.

So something like this:

```
fixedlat = 51.714236;
fixedlon = 50.710236

for data... {

    var result = checkDistance(fixedlat, fixedlon, datalat, datalon);

    if (result <= 20) {

      //append data[name] to div id="resultList"

    }   

}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example, assuming your distance formula is for geodesic over a sphere, for example by making use of the Haversine formula.

```js
function checkDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}

var fixedlat = 51.714236;
var fixedlon = 50.710236;
var miles = 20;
var distanceLimit = miles * 1.6; //(km)
var data = [
  {
    "name": "Paul Brooks",
    "location": {
      "lat": 51.714236,
      "lon": 50.710236
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Jason Orange",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52.030778298795856,
      "lon": 0.364888567109396
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark Way",
    "location": {
      "lat": 53.41899784623413,
      "lon": -1.9138465628943413
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Ben Bon",
    "location": {
      "lat": 52.30976192959104,
      "lon": -0.4014670363034498
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Chris Col",
    "location": {
      "lat": 53.45301856182801,
      "lon": -1.8765834388107732
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Von Van",
    "location": {
      "lat": 53.82771812914788,
      "lon": -0.7563793003592991
    }
  }
];

for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){ 

 var result = checkDistance(fixedlat,fixedlon,data[i].location.lat,data[i].location.lon);

 if(result <= distanceLimit){
  var resultList = document.getElementById('resultList');
  resultList.append(data[i].name + ', ');
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="resultList"></div>
```

Comment: Just 1 question please... the 10000 is returning: 3426.1437014203716 is this meters? I need to say: if(result <= 20 miles){ ... do something

Comment: It's now updated it to show the names now as requested. The unit from checkDistance function is km

Comment: Ok the limit is now at 20 miles and Paul Brooks has been moved within the distance, best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a .forEach() function on an array by default.
So you can create the loop as the following.

```js
var data = [] // Your data
data.forEach(function(item){
  var datalong = item.location.lon;
  var datalat = item.location.lat;
  
});
```